# Ubuntu won't boot beyond tty1 screen

Tags: 15.04

I had upgraded to 15.04 few days back. Yesterday, I tried downloading a noobslab Mac theme and played and also changed the default graphic driver. Now, the GUI won't booot. I have tried following methods that are not working:

1. Apt-get upgrade - failed to fetch certain files
2. Tried installing xorg drivers. Won't work
3. Tried installing unity desktop and lightdm - xorg and amd 64.deb error
4. Tried to install Ubuntu desktop - still same failed to fetch error
5. Tried connecting to internet - could'nt. I had uninstalled network managed and added some other software.

Sorry for being a noob but all my work is stuck. All help would be appreciated

Comment: Perhaps you should add the error messages by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: I don't know how to post logs here. Can someone help?

Comment: Edit your question via [Edit], add the error messages and format as code via the button in the editor.

Comment: There are no buttons here :( I am posting from phone. Is there a way to post an image here?

Comment: Add the error messages without a formatting. A will reformat your question.

Comment: I guess I don't have enough repuatation to post more than 2 links

Comment: Replace http with an placeholder.

Comment: Can the issue be solved? Of does it need formatting ?

Comment: You have not posted the error messages.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/posts/687613/revisions

Answer (score -2):

Here's how I solve problem to login again:

I press ctrl+alt+F1, give username and password.  Then I run

```
$mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

Then I press ctrl+alt+F7
Then login page is open; I type password, and can then login again.

I'm running 15.04 version.